# Get references to EmberJS views created for a given model object?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a list of `DefinedWord` objects, which are each rendered in an `{{#each}}` block as a list of `DefinedWordView` divs at the bottom of the page.

When a user clicks a word, I lookup the associated `DefinedWord`. Now I want a reference to the `DefinedWordView` rendered for this `DefinedWord`, so I can `ScrollTo()` the `DefinedWordView`'s div.

I can always have the views stamp each model object with a back-reference when they load, but it seems a little ugly. Not a big deal, but I think I'll need to do this for lots of other operations, and I'd rather not litter my model objects with back-references to views.

Anyone have suggestions for an `ember-y` idiom to handle this? Maybe `EmberJS` needs a standard **"singleton view registry"** or something?

Comment: Maybe you could render a uid of your DefinedWord into each view. Then you could fetch the div via jQuery. This would result in something like: $('.definedWordView#'definedWord.get('id'));
But i guess you consider this being a dirty trick?

Comment: Nah, that'd be one of the ok ways to go, but I'm fishing to see if there's a way to do this from within the Ember layers....

Comment: If you give an id to your view, I think you could access it through the Ember.View.views["yourId"]. Not sure if it works, but you can try it :)

Comment: Any of these require manually tracking the relationship between Model and View....

Comment: What do u mean by when a user clicks a word ? is that a different word from defined word ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your model use the `Em.Evented` mixin:

```
App.Word = Em.Object.extend(Em.Evented, {
  // ...
});
```

When your model is clicked, trigger an event on it, let's call it `selected`.

```
App.WordView = Em.View.extend({
  click: function () {
    // content == the model
    this.get('content').trigger('selected');
  }
})
```

The model's view can bind to that event and when it's fired, scroll to itself:

```
// just pseudo code:
App.DefinedWordView = Em.View.extend({
  init: function () {
    this._super();

    //listen for the 'selected' event and call 'scrollToDefinition' on 'this'
    this.get('content').on('selected', this, 'scrollToDefinition');
  },

  scrollToDefinition: function () {
    $(document).scrollTo( this.$() );
  }
})
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, because it was the primary inspiration for my final solution, found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13664463/294247 . I don't think using properties for signalling is right, but its a simple modification to use Ember.Evented or simply use Ember.sendEvent directly

Comment: Feel free to improve your answer using the code from mine, if you agree about using Ember.Evented, I didn't want to put words into your mouth.

Comment: @Seth TIL that Ember.Evented exists. I don't like using properties for signaling but I didn't know a better way. Feel free to accept your own answer, or change mine.

Comment: @Seth, since you haven't accepted your own answer, I changed my answer to incorporate yours. Let me know if it could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638139/294247 was great, but it didn't seem right to use a property for signalling. I realized I should be using Events dispatched from the object, and letting views react as appropriate.

Using the Ember.Evented mixin:

```
App.DefinedWord = Ember.Object.extend(Ember.Evented, {
    // ...
    scrollToDefinition: function () {
        this.trigger('scrollToDefinition');
    }
});

App.DefinedWordView = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function () {
        this._super();
        this.get('content').on('scrollToDefinition', this, 'scrollToDefinition');
    },
    scrollToDefinition: function () {
        $(document).scrollTo(this.$());
    }
});
```