# Ember.js: Design pattern for communicating to view from model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

What's the design pattern for accessing a model's view from the model?

I have an `Item` DS.Model, `ItemController`, `ItemsController`, and `ItemView`, linked together with the standard `render` in the template that iterates over the ItemsController's content:

items.hbs:

```
{{#each item in content}}
   render 'item' item
{{/each}}
```

I also have a `newItem` event on the `ItemsController`, which just creates a new Item object and prepends it into the controller's content array:

items_controller:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  actions:
    newItem: ->
      newItem = @get('store').createRecord 'item'
      @get('content').insertAt(0, item, 0)
```

This works fine: after the next run loop, a new ItemController + ItemView are created and the changes are reflected in the DOM automatically.

However, say I want to set the mouse focus on an element inside the newly inserted ItemView (call a function `focusMe`), which seems like it reduces to **how can I access (or send events to) a model's view from the model?** I know in general information flows one-way from model -> controller -> view in Ember, but how else would I accomplish this?

**Thoughts:**

1. `didInsertElement` won't work, because I only want to call `focusMe` for items created via the `newItem` action, and I don't want to couple it with every view.
2. It seems like the most logical place to do this is inside the `newItem` action definition itself, something like `newItem.getView().focusMe()`, but of course this requires access to the model's view.
3. I looked at [Get references to EmberJS views created for a given model object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626325/get-references-to-emberjs-views-created-for-a-given-model-object), but I think adding an observer for every single `ItemView` is overkill, when only newly created items via the `newItem` action need to be focused.
4. Also, I tried that solution, and couldn't get it to work (that answer is over a year old).

Comment: if you're using ember data, you could rely on the 'isNew' property, I set up a JSFiddle, it is not using ember data, I just defined the 'isNew' property there, but 'isNew' is in ember data, so you should not have any problems http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/836/

Comment: @fanta thanks for the idea. I think that's pretty similar to the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626325/get-references-to-emberjs-views-created-for-a-given-model-object . I'm wondering if there's a better approach, since this adds an observer for every single one of the model views, when we only care about newly created ones.